# What is maximum value for tinyint(2) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

What is the maximum value allowed for a column of type `tinyint(2)`?

Are values like 255 or 99 allowed? I am confused because `(2)` after `tinyint(2)` denotes only the display... Am  I correct?

Answer (score 20):

It takes 127.

refer link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Why it takes 127 ?? what is the meaning of tinyint(2)??

Comment: Looks like 127 is for Signed TINTYINT(1) not for Signed TINYINT(2). So what's the value for Signed TINYINT(2) ? Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 12):

[MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual: Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly.

**Edit:** No. Note that `UNSIGNED` is a non-standard attribute that affects the range. Neither value given in your question is the correct upper-limit of a *normal* `TINYINT(2)`.

**Edit for the comment edit:** Trust the documentation unless there is a reason not to. If something seems fishy, TIAS (try it and see).

Comment: so you guys mean that 127 is the maximum allowed value here ?

Comment: Yes, 127 is the maximum value for signed tinyint. Btw, is it so difficult to try?

Answer (score 9):

For tinyint data type:
if db column is SIGNED   : min:-128 , max:`127` 
if db column is UNSIGNED : min:0    , max:`255`
Just this.

more help! :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 4):

I believe the correct answer to this question is:

```
255
```

not 127.

Check this page out: [Mysql Integer types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html)

What other answers are failing to tell you is that the maximum can be 255 if you don't use negative numbers.

If you're using negative numbers then the maximum value can only be 127.

That's really what the `unsigned` and `signed` words mean, unfortunately no one explained this to you so I can see why it's confusing.

`usigned` means it cannot contain negative numbers so if you set your column to be `unsigned` then you can use `255` as the maximum. If you don't explicitly set the column as `unsigned` it means it will accept negative numbers (thus being a `signed` column) in which case the maximum will now be `127`.

The other answers are technically correct because by default Mysql will set all integer columns as `signed` (able to use negative numbers). I just think this answer explains things a little more and is, perhaps, more germane to your original question.